# How can I log shell errors in scripts called by a cron job?

Tags: shell-script, cron, stderr

This morning I found a message saying just so:

**EDIT**: I add the header of the message as well, so it is clear where it came from.

```
Return-Path: <root@REDACTED>
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
  (uid 0)
  by REDACTED with local
  id 00000000005DC0DF.00000000633BA87E.000042C7; Tue, 04 Oct 2022 05:29:02 +0200
From: CronDaemon <root@REDACTED>
To: admlog@REDACTED
Subject: Cron <root@north> test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <MAILTO=REDACTED>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-ID: <courier.00000000633BA87E.000042C7@REDACTED>
Date: Tue, 04 Oct 2022 05:29:02 +0200
X-Mime-Autoconverted: from 8bit to 7bit by courier 1.1

/etc/cron.daily/syslogrotate:
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
```

I modified `syslogrotate` to call a shell script that looks at the rotated files, calling other scripts as needed.  Cron attributes anything written to stderr to the first process it launched.  It would be nice to know the actual script file, maybe even the line number.  Isn't there a tool that does just that?

Comment: (1) If the issue comes from a modified logrotate script, it is not a cron issue. You should debug the logrotate script you wrote. (2) Where is that message coming from? email, syslog, something else ? (3) Where do you want to log errors? In an specific file, in the syslog utility, or receive an error email ?

Comment: (1) No, it's not a cron issue.  I must have written something like `if [ $what -gt 0]`, where once in a blue moon `$what` is not numeric. (2) message from cron.  (3) cron messaging is fine, just not quite actionable...

Comment: Yes, I understand that you are set in saying that the error is generated by cron, understood. But, the source that has convinced you is not clear in your post. So, I am asking how do you come to such conclusion? Because you receive an email from cron wiith that error? Or, because you were looking at the error logs and found that error logged there? or, Something else?

Comment: If `rsyslog` (or `syslog` if that is what you use) is fine (from your comment), then I recommend you to try to log your cron scripts with: `0 8 * * * /usr/local/bin/myjob  2>&1 | logger -t myjoblog`. That will not debug the modified `syslogrotate` unless you take additional actions. But We can not give any more specific recommendations over an unknown script code.

Comment: @αғsнιη that is a typo in the comment.  Possibly, that was a wrong guess anyway, as 'Invalid numeric literal' can be caused by `jq`.  That considerably restricts the possible error locations.  However, the general question remains of how can one instrument bash scripts in order to get more context when an error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Have the script that syslog invokes check the exit code of each sub-task it invokes and when the sub-task exits with a non-zero code, the script writes a message to stderr that says the path and name of the script.  For example, `/path/to/the/sub_task.sh returned exit code 2`.  That message will be included in the e-mail from cron and you will get the script name you're hoping for.

Comment: The idea is good, except that setting and then checking return codes is often neglected —otherwise the code would need no debugging.  It'd be interesting to have a a function to check output status.  `if error_occurred; then echo ${BASH_SOURCE[*]}; clear_error; fi`

Comment: Yes, I presumed the asker of this question has the ability to modify the script that's being called from cron.  After all, the question begins with `I modified syslogrotate to call a shell script, calling other scripts as needed.`  I myself have written such supervisory scripts that call other scripts and/or commands as sub-tasks, and it's perfectly viable to check the exit code of each sub-task and output a message to stderr/stdout based on the code.

Answer (score 0):

No. There are no such tools.

But `bash` has a few tools to find a bug.

```
#!/bin/bash -v
```

And your script will print each command before executing. This will show where exactly the error happened.

Or you can use key `-x` for `bash`. This will give even more information on the execution of the script.

If you localized a bug to a small portion of the script and do not want to print all of it anymore, you can use `set -xv`:

```
#!/bin/bash
some-good-commands
set -xv  # debug mode on
some-suspicious-code
set +xv  # debug mode off
some-good-commands
```

These could be used directly in a cron job if manual run of the script does not give you an idea on what is the source of the problem.

And of course, you can always add a debugging `echo`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting script A"
VAR=$1
echo "Executing `abc $VAR`"
abc $VAR
echo "abc ended with $?"
```

Comment: Any output would trigger a cron email, so I want to output something only when the error occurs.  Bash has variables like `BASH_COMMAND`, `BASH_LINENO`, `BASH_SOURCE` that could be printed right after an unexpected output occurs, to add context, but how do I know that happened?  Alternatively, the script could be launched by a program which monitors stdout and stderr (like cron does), but how can it access those bash variables when it sees an output?

Comment: That is why it is always better to debug the script first in a manual mode. Once you caught all bugs - put the script in cron. New errors - go back to manual debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Sotto Voce's idea is good.  Rather than testing the return code, one can test if anything was written out.  That way one can instrument cron scripts to write some context in case of error.

I don't know how to test output in bash, so I wrote a little C utility named `any_output`:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long cur_out = lseek(1, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (cur_out < 0) cur_out = 0;
    long cur_err = lseek(2, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (cur_err < 0) cur_err = 0;
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        char *slash, *end;
        long last_out = strtol(argv[1], &slash, 10);
        if (*slash == '/')
        {
            long last_err = strtol(slash + 1, &end, 10);
            if (*end != 0 && *end != '\n')
                last_err = -1;
            else
            {
                int rtc = cur_err > last_err || cur_out > last_out;
                if (rtc)
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s, %ld > %ld || %ld > %ld\n",
                        argv[1], cur_err, last_err, cur_out, last_out);
                return rtc;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fputs("argument to any_output is its previous output\n", stderr);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%ld/%ld\n", cur_out, cur_err);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Next I wrote a test script.  It calls `jq` since that was the error I got.

```bash
#! /bin/bash

output=$(/home/ale/tmp/any_output)
if [ -f /home/ale/tmp/test.data ]; then
    if [[ "$(jq .j < /home/ale/tmp/test.data)" != "1" ]]; then
        touch /home/ale/tmp/test.data
    fi
fi
/home/ale/tmp/any_output $output || echo ${BASH_SOURCE[*]}
```

The path is that of my current directory. test.data contained just `{"j":1}` so that the script is almost a no op.  I set up crontab to call my test script every two minutes.  Nothing happened for a while, until I wrote `hello` to test.data.  On the next run, cron mailed me this:

```
From: CronDaemon <REDACTED>
To: REDACTED
Subject: Cron <ale@pcale> /home/ale/tmp/test.sh
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <MAILTO=REDACTED>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/ale>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=ale>
Date: Thu, 06 Oct 2022 14:18:01 +0200
X-Mime-Autoconverted: from 8bit to 7bit by courier 1.0

parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
0/0, 57 > 0 || 57 > 0
/home/ale/tmp/test.sh
```

That gibberish in the second line of the body serves to debug the instrument itself.  I had some false positives because `lseek(1, 0, SEEK_END)` was returning -1, even through `isatty(1)` was false.  So I removed the call to `isatty` and set the code as above.